# Transpose columns to rows in Microsoft Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a column in excel suppose

```
12
13
12
12
34
```

I want to change it in row like

```
2 13 12 12 34
```

I tried to tranpose it but All the changed data go in single cell. I need to copy column and dump it in row each cell one value

Comment: how did you try to transpose it?

Answer (score 2):

1. Choose the appropriate column.
2. Copy.
3. Choose the first cell of tow.
4. Right mouse button - Paste Special - mark the transpose checkbox.
5. Ok.

The result is a inserted column in a row.