# how to transpose groups of rows to columns

Tags: microsoft-excel

My source table looks like this

```
ID   Product   Amount
22   product1  $10
22   product2  $20
22   product3  $30
33   product2  $4
33   product3  $5
44   product1  $78
44   product4  $90
```

Here's the final table I need:

```
ID  product1 product2 product3 product4
22       $10      $20      $30     
33                 $4       $5
44       $78                        $90
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Transpose columns to rows in Microsoft Excel](http://superuser.com/questions/553666/transpose-columns-to-rows-in-microsoft-excel)

Comment: Not a duplicate.  This isn't just transposing, it's reorganizing.

Answer (score 4):

That can be accomplished by using a Pivot Table. With a single cell or the entire table selected, navigate to  `Insert` ► `Tables` ► `Pivot Table`

Then drag ID to the Rows area, Product to the Columns area, and Amount to the Values area.  Play around with the formatting and labelling until you get what you want:

[image]

Comment: what if we have another column whose rows are guaranteed to have the same value per group? i.e. same as the `ID` column, just another column. Can we transpose it into a column as well?

Comment: @HeyJude Yes, you can.  The methodology may be different. Suggest you pose a question with data, desired results, and show what you have tried and explain what went wrong.

Comment: thanks, just did: [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1725472/transpose-groups-of-rows-to-columns-where-each-group-is-based-on-two-columns).

Answer (score 1):

With data like this in *Sheet1*:

[image]

Running short macro:

```
Sub TwoDee()
    Dim s1 As Worksheet, s2 As Worksheet
    Dim N As Long, i As Long, v1 As String, v2 As String, v3 As Long
    Dim iRow As Long, iCol As Long
    Set s1 = Sheets("Sheet1")
    Set s2 = Sheets("Sheet2")
    s2.Cells.Clear

    N = s1.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    s1.Range("A2:B" & N).Copy s2.Range("A2")
    s2.Range("A:A").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    s2.Range("B:B").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=1, Header:=xlNo
    s2.Range("B2:B" & N).Copy
    s2.Range("B1").PasteSpecial Transpose:=True
    s2.Range("B2:B" & N).Clear

    For i = 2 To N
        v1 = s1.Cells(i, 1).Value
        v2 = s1.Cells(i, 2).Value
        v3 = s1.Cells(i, 3).Value
        iRow = s2.Range("A:A").Find(What:=v1, After:=s2.Range("A1")).Row
        iCol = s2.Range("1:1").Find(What:=v2, After:=s2.Range("A1")).Column
        s2.Cells(iRow, iCol) = v3
    Next i
End Sub
```

will produce this in *Sheet2*:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/transpose.html

First hit on Google for excel 2010 transpose.

Basically, you select all the data you want to transpose, (including any column or row headers) Ctrl + C to copy it, right click on the top left cell where you want to paste it and paste special
Check the transpose box and hit ok, and you're done.

Comment: I'd mark this as a duplicate if I could.
http://superuser.com/questions/553666/transpose-columns-to-rows-in-microsoft-excel?rq=1

Comment: Please read the question carefully.  It is not about transposing.