# transpose groups of rows to columns, where each group is based on two columns

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

Similar to [how to transpose groups of rows to columns](https://superuser.com/questions/1122833/how-to-transpose-groups-of-rows-to-columns), but with an additional requirement:

How to do the transposition if each group is based on two columns?

Also:
Would the answer be the same if the additional column (`OnSale` in the example below) is guaranteed to have the same value for the group?

For example, if the source table is:

```
ID   Product   Amount  OnSale
22   product1  $10       1
22   product2  $20       1
22   product3  $30       0
33   product2  $4        1
33   product3  $5        1
44   product1  $78       0
44   product4  $90       0
```

Then the final table should be:

```
ID  product1 product2 product3 product4 OnSale
22       $10      $20                       1
22                         $30              0
33                 $4       $5              1
44       $78                        $90     0
```

I tried [the accepted answer](https://superuser.com/a/1123067/566258) of the aforementioned question, but using an additional column doesn't seem to work:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would sugget you use Power Query to have a check.

- Select the whole table, go to Data > Get & Transform Data group > Click From Table/Range.

[image]

- Go to File > Transform group > Click Group By. Group the data via ID, Product and OnSale. (The New column name will be Count as default.)

[image]

- Press Ctrl key to choose Product and Count columns. Go to Transform > Any Column tab > Click Pivot Column.

[image]

- There will be a icon after each "Product" header. You can click it to choose "Amount" to expand the "Table" that generated via group operaction.

[image]

[image]

- At last, you can click File > Load to, load the table to your sheet.

[image]